# Error when trying to connect to Teradata as source using Attunity

Tags: teradata, attunity

I am getting the following error when I try to connect to Teradata as source using attunity

"SYS-E-HTTPFAIL, Cannot connect to ODBC provider Fatal error has occurred."

I have restarted Attunity console and server

[screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCndB.png)

I confirmed that Teradata ODBC is installed and I can connect to Teradata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for these errors:

1- In my case I needed to update the environment variable and ensure to enter the correct path to Teradata ODBC driver

2- Other reasons for the error is ensure you are running a 64 bit ODBC driver matching Attunity 64 bit download